# How to destroy/capture enemy HQ?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I am playing the CoH campaign and I had a secondary objective to wipe out a secondary German base. I did that and now there is only one rubble-looking structure "Destroyed HQ". I assume I am to capture it somehow, but I can't figure out a way how. Help me out please

Comment: Which campaign level are you on?

Comment: 6 - Cherbourg (http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Company_of_Heroes_-_PC/Walkthrough#MISSION_06:_Cherbourg)

Comment: According to that guide, there's not a secondary objective to destroy a German base.  That's the primary objective in the level.  Are you sure you've got the right level in mind?  When you destroy the German base, the level should end.

Comment: My bad. It's the level 5 :/ Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to consider the HQ destroyed you have to destroy EVERY building in that base. If you take a look at [this link](http://guides.gamepressure.com/companyofheroes/guide.asp?ID=1458) you'll see that there is a big square around the HQ in question. Until you have destroyed the base in its entirety it will not be counted as completed. The guide also says it takes some time, so make sure you got it all.

If you got all of the buildings it is possible the game is glitched, but I see nothing stating that this is a common glitch and since the game is fairly old I would think this would be documented by now.

Comment: I did destroy all the buildings. I did receive a "Quest completed" notification, but the ruins of HQ still stood there. Meh.

Comment: Oh, well those are just the smoldering remains of defeat.

Comment: Weird for the remains to appear on the minimap and making the territory enemy :/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer's link shows, you must destroy all of the buildings in the [green area on the map](http://guides.gamepressure.com/companyofheroes/gfx/word/1006472578.jpg). If you have already destroyed these buildings, yet do not get the award upon completing the mission, the enemy may have rebuilt some of the base if you left it unguarded.

**German engineers may spawn on the map and repair the headquarters.** If this is in the 'fog of war' (area on the map that is currently shaded and out of sight), you will not see that it has been repaired, and thus, it will still look destroyed to you.

To ensure that the base remains destroyed, you should **leave a unit at the headquarters to guard it**, and prevent it from being repaired.

The same applies to multiplayer matches. (players can spawn extra engineers after their HQ is destroyed in order to repair their headquarters)

Answer (score 0):

The HQ is a single building where they can make their engineers (starting units). You can't capture the building, you can only destroy it. Once you have destroyed this single building the objective should be completed.